# gulp-kraken not working on subfolders path

Tags: image, path, gulp, compression, kraken-image-optimizer

creating a task on gulp:

```
imgCompressionTask = () => {
return src('dest/**/img/*.*') 
.pipe(kraken({ key: '', secret: '', lossy: true, concurrency: 6 }))
}
```

```
'dest/hello/img/*.*'
```

it works, but thats just 1 folder and I need to make it work in subfolders, therefore:

```
'dest/**/img/*.*'
```

Any idea?

using last stable versions of node npm gulp and kraken io

Thank you so much in advance!

I try:

```
dest/**/img/*.*
```

I was expecting gulp-kraken to use that path to compress images inside the subfolders